# How do I do this SELECT statement that uses column renaming (or column alias) with LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq

How do I get 'anotherColumnName' in LINQ?

```
SELECT thisColumnName as anotherColumnName FROM TableName
```

I have the following which obviously gives me 'thisColumnName' not 'anotherColumnName'

```
    var query = from names in _context.TableName
                select names;
    return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate [Using custom column names in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128277/using-custom-column-names-in-linq)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an anonymous type:

```
var query = (from name in _context.Table
            select new { anotherColumnName = name.ColumnName });
```

Answer (score 1):

For the finished solution I also needed a bit extra as below.

Old version.

```
public List<OldClassName> GetSomething()
{
    var query = from names in _context.OldClassNames
                select names;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

New version with column renaming.

```
public List<NewClassName> GetSomething()
{
    var query = from names in _context.OldClassNames
                select new NewClassName
                {
                    NewColumName = names.OldColumnName
                };
    return query.ToList();
}
```